# Industry Standard For Infrastructure As Code

Tags: aws-cloudformation, devops, azure-resource-manager, infrastructure-as-code

Does anyone know or have a reference to a set of existing or emerging standards for Infrastructure-As-Code?  I'm looking for a definition of cloud deployment assets that I could use as a basis for an environment definition that could be translated or projected into either an AWS Cloudformation Template or an Azure Resource Management Deployment Template.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Stack is such a standard.
AWS have such a standard.
KVM have such a standard.

There exists no "industry" standard across vendor stacks, however there are tooling that abstract the vendor specifics out. One such tooling would be Puppet.

Comment: I think the standard you are referring too would be ARM templates vs. CloudFormation Templates is that correct?  I was looking for something that both of those may have been based on to find the common ground but I agree as of the moment I can only seem to find tooling like Terraform that goes through the pain of translating a canonical definition to a vendor specific template rendering

Comment: Well you seem to be already more advanced than me in the understanding of this.
There are however lots of other approaches to doing IaC. We chose an approach using only custom made PowerShell modules. We managed to meet all our IaC demands with under 3k lines of powershell code.
But this is kinda "going the other way" than you seem to want. Where you are looking for the canonical IaC descriptive language, we just went with a pragmatic approach that covers our needs, which is Microsoft on-premise platforms only.